# C program for Selling banana

Tags: c

Can anybody help me fix my `(choice == 3)`,I have a problem when im trying sell my banana's, it doesn't subtract exactly what i input

for example: `choice 1. harvest banana`

I harvest 2 times, in `Day 1` i harvested 100 in `Day 2`i harvested 150

so when viewing my `choice 2. View Stocks` output will be this

```
Day    QTY
 1      100
 2      150
```

total of 250 banana's

Now lets go `choice 3. Sell banana` I enter number of banana's order is: `101`

when viewing the stocks again it shows wrong output

```
Day    QTY
 1        0
 2      150
```

as you can see it it only decreased by `100`, where is the `1` go ?

```
int main(void){
    int choice = 0;
    int days = 1, i, banana;
    int stocks[99] = {0};

    for (;;) {
        clrscr();
        printf("Day %d\n", days);

        printf("1. harvest banana\n");
        printf("2. View Stocks\n");
        printf("3. Sell banana\n");
        printf("\nchoice: ");

        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1){

            clrscr();
            printf("Enter number of banana harvested: ");
            scanf("%d", &stocks[days]);
            days++;
        }

        if (choice == 2){
            clrscr();
            printf("Day    QTY\n");

            for (i = 1; i < days; i++){
                printf("%2d     %4d\n", i, stocks[i]);
            }
            getch();
        }
        if(choice == 3){
            printf("Enter number of banana's order: ");
            scanf("%d", &banana);

            for (i = 1; i < banana; i++){
                if (banana <= stocks[i]){
                    stocks[i] = stocks[i] - banana;
                    banana = 0;
                }else{
                    banana = banana - stocks[i];
                    stocks[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i < banana` can't continue loop after banana become  to 1.

Comment: But... but... how can it be a duplicate. This one is about bananas, the other one was about apples!

Comment: Also exists egg version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You for loop condition is false :

```
for (i = 1; i < banana; i++){
```

Must be

```
for (i = 1; banana && i < 99; i++){
```

(loop until there is no more banana left or until there is no stock left).
Note that using "magic" number like 99 in your code may be dangerous, since when you'll want to change the amout it will be hard to find all "99" in your code, leading to false behavior.
In additon, array start at 0, not 1, so you should fix that.

I suggest you to use a define, like :

```
#define ARRAY_LEN 99
...
int stocks[ARRAY_LEN] = {0};
...
for (i = 0; banana && i < ARRAY_LEN; i++){
```

And one last advide : indent your code, it will be easier for you to read it.

Comment: Your fix has a problem. If the total of the stock is less than `banana`,  loop does not  be finished.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think hard enought, I will correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The loop will be like this

```
for (i = 1;  banana!=0; i++)
```